# overflow: auto with persistent header

Tags: css, list, scroll, overflow, css-position

I'm trying to create a scrollable list with a persistent nav header.  However when you scroll to the bottom of the list the last few items are not visible, as the list is pushed down by the header.  I created a jsfiddle to show the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/U34vq/12/

The problem is the height: 100%.  How can I fix this?  I *could* use CSS3 calc() to make it, height: calc(100% - 3em);  However I'm targeting browsers that don't support calc().

I guess my question is, can I have 2 nested elements, one with height measured in ems and the other in % and have that work, because it seems like I cannot.

Comment: Not sure if I totally understand what you're after but is this close: http://jsfiddle.net/U34vq/13/

Comment: or maybe this one http://jsfiddle.net/U34vq/14/

Comment: @AntonBoritskiy Looking for a css solution, thanks though.

Comment: @BillyMoat Yes, it is close, thank you. I need the scrollbars to be on .items though.  I think the only way I can do it is to make both nav and .items be % height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this solution. I have added `position: absolute;` to the items and set the `bottom` and `top` parameters as well, seems to work ok

http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/U34vq/15/

Comment: Wow!  This actually seems to work perfect, which I wasn't exactly expecting to see. Thank you!